# Problems with aligning text and images

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems while trying to align image and text. If I write a text long enough, the text renders below the image, kinda like if had a `<br>`. Take a look:

[image: Problem occurring]

How can I solve this? Is there a better way to do this? Here's my code:

Thanks in advance!

```css
.juices img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.juice {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="juices">
  <!--C.Juices-->
  <div>
    <!--Produto 1-->
    <article class="border artigo">
      <div style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
      </div>
      <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <h1>WATERMELON BLISS</h1>
        <p>
          Sinta todo o frescor da melancia no seu vape! Com nossos liquidos especiais, feitos especialmente com flavorizantes extraidos em nossos laboratórios, você possui todo o sabor da fruta.
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div>
    <!--Produto 2-->
    <article class="border artigo">
      <div style="float: right;">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
      </div>
      <div style="display: inline-block; float: right;">
        <h1> STRAWBERRY WATERMELONADE</h1>
      </div>
      <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
<!--F.Juices-->
```

Comment: You haven't told us what outcome you're after. Please see [ask] and revise to be more clear.

Comment: Protips: For this layout, floats probably aren't ideal. There are better, more modern methods of doing layout. Also, don't use inline styles. They're a pain for you and for us. Use custom classes with intuitive, semantic names.

Answer (score 0):

You want the image to always be displayed next to the text? There are, as so often, many solutions. I always like to do this with Flexbox (no floats neaded):

```
.juices article{
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
.artigo{
    display: flex
}
```

is this what you wanted to do?

Comment: @idokido, please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: flex`. See the snippet below.

```css
.artigo {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.artigo img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.artigo > div { padding: 1rem }
```

```html
<div class="juices">
  <!--C.Juices-->
  <div>
    <!--Produto 1-->
    <article class="border artigo">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
      <div>
        <h1>WATERMELON BLISS</h1>
        <p>
          Sinta todo o frescor da melancia no seu vape! Com nossos liquidos especiais, feitos especialmente com flavorizantes extraidos em nossos laboratórios, você possui todo o sabor da fruta.
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
  <div>
    <!--Produto 2-->
    <article class="border artigo">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
      <div>
        <h1> STRAWBERRY WATERMELONADE</h1>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
<!--F.Juices-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a width to your text div:

```html
<div class="juices">
  <!--C.Juices-->
  <div>
    <!--Produto 1-->
    <article class="border artigo">
      <img src="image source">
      <div style=" display: inline-block;width: 50%;">
        <h1>WATERMELON BLISS</h1>
        <p>
          Sinta todo o frescor da melancia no seu vape! Com nossos liquidos especiais, feitos especialmente com flavorizantes extraidos em nossos laboratórios, você possui todo o sabor da fruta.
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[click here to sea output. I thing this is you ask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tElBB.png)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    .juices img {
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
        font-size: 20px;
      }
      
      .juice {
        width: 250px;
        height: 250px;
        font-size: 20px;
      }
      article{
        width: 250px;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="juices" style="width: 100% ;">
        
        
          <!--Produto 1-->
          <article>
            <div>
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
            </div>
            <div>
              <h1>WATERMELON BLISS</h1>
              <p>
                Sinta todo o frescor da melancia no seu vape! Com nossos liquidos especiais, feitos especialmente com flavorizantes extraidos em nossos laboratórios, você possui todo o sabor da fruta.
              </p>
            </div>
          </article>
        
        
          <!--Produto 2-->
          <article style="float:right;">
            <div>
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
            </div>
            <div>
              <h1> STRAWBERRY WATERMELONADE</h1>
            </div>
          </article>
        
    </div>
      <!--F.Juices-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).